# Instance member 'index' cannot be used on type 'RouteAction'

Tags: ios, swift

I declared property in class:

```
class RouteAction {

    var index: Int = 0
```

And I try use(print) `index` in my method:

```
class func workingWithIndex() {

  print(index)
}
```

but see error

> Instance member 'index' cannot be used on type 'RouteAction'

Why and how can I use `index` in my method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Index` is an instance variable, so it'd have to be something like:

```
class func workingWithIndex()
{
    let action = RouteAction()
    print (action.index)
}
```